# How ignore file with error when adding into SVN

Tags: svn, addition, ignore, fifo, svnignore

I'm adding some file into svn, so I do `svn add *`.
But the command will stop immediately when he found some error file (FIFO file in my case) and didn't continue the process for other files.

```
svn: Can't detect MIME type of non-file 'ASMX.INTR/in'
```

How can I add file into svn with ignoring error files ?

I also try :

```
svn add * --force
entersvn propset svn:ignore -R *.in. ; svn propset svn:ignore -R *.out.
```

But nothing works. So if someone can help me.

Comment: If you know which files/folders will cause trouble, you can add them to ignore list: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch07s02.html#svn-ch-7-sect-2.3.3

Comment: I try it, but when i do `svn add` i have the same trouble.

Comment: If you have the same trouble, it means that ignore list is not set properly, otherwise, 'svn add' would not try to process these files/folders.